# Post to User's Facebook wall from javaScript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to use the Facebook SDK to post to a users wall. I just can't seem to get it right and still receive `This does not let the app post to Facebook.` on any of my permissions boxes.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    // handle the response
}, {
    scope: 'user_location,user_likes,user_posts',
    return_scopes: true
});
```

I believe that the `user_posts` permission is what is needed, but clearly its not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `publish_actions` permission in order to publish posts on behalf of a user.

The `user_posts` permission provides access to user's timeline (**but** not only posts of user).

Take a look at [permissions reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#review).

Comment: Its been 5 years since I've worked with FB and still.... even now its so  poorly documented. Why isn't this obvious. Thanks very much :) Interesting that this does not change the text `This does not let the app post to Facebook.` In the "Log in with facebook" dialog

Comment: They made a lot of changes to their API... Also, keep in mind that your app should be reviewed if you require `publish_actions` permission.

Comment: At this point it only for testing. But of course I will be happy to have it reviewed. I point isn't about what has changed, more about that its near impossible to work out these things through their documentation :) Also I see that it takes you to a second screen when it warns you about posting to your wall.